# Is there a way to create method hooks for structs in Go?

Tags: go

I want to create before save and after save method hooks for my Go structs how can I achieve this?

```
    type Person struct {
        FirstName string
        LastName string
    }

    func (p *Person) Save() {
        // call beforeSave()
        // Save person data
        // call afterSave()
    }

    func (p *Person) Update() {
        // call beforeUpdate()
        // Update person data
        // call afterUpdate()
    }

    type Order struct {
        Number bson.ObjectId
        Items []Item
    }

    func (o *Order) Save() {
        // call beforeSave()
        // Save order data
        // call afterSave()
    }

    func (o *Order) Update() {
        // call beforeUpdate()
        // Update order data
        // call afterUpdate()
    }
```

For any struct I create as a model I want it to have a beforeSave() and afterSave() hook called automatically and be able to further override if necessary.

Comment: A descriptive sample would help others understand your question better. Is the struct itself is used somewhere else? Or is the interface of the struct the only thing that matters? You can provide a working example at https://play.golang.org/

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You have already written the code in your question, commented out. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is I want some way to automatically call those functions without having to write beforeSave() and afterSave() in every struct.

Answer (score 3):

Packages like [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) use callback hooks heavily. But if you are writing your own engine (for some specific logic) using interfaces can help greatly ([sample](https://play.golang.org/p/Eq_EBz8PtPf)).

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@matryer/the-http-handler-wrapper-technique-in-golang-updated-bc7fbcffa702

I would only add to that article above, which I think well answers your question, that you can go further using pipelines (methods that return the associated variable they are bound to). It's particularly interesting as in the above article, as relates to being able to interpose anything between two processes, and you can use this to create tees and journalling/logging systems, and it can go a long way towards compensating for the kinda primitive error handling in Go.

I designed a number of related byte slice processing libraries that were able to be easily chained without needing to break a a line, although obviously more than about 3-4 in a line can get confusing and you can find yourself wanting to pass things in a DAG style pattern, at which point I think channels would make sense.